# When using youtube-dl with ffmpeg, what merge extension(mkv/mp4) can get best sound quality

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, youtube-dl

I use **youtube-dl -F** to display all video/audio list, and choose best video/audio source myself.

Then I use **youtube-dl -f [video code]+[audio code]** to download and automatically merge them.

As question title, when I use **--merge-output-format**, what output extension should be chosen then I can get a file with best sound quality. Is mkv? Or is most suitable merge extension related to the extension of video/audio source?

By the way, my using player is PotPlayer.

Answer (score 4):

## It doesn't really matter

- MKV or MP4 can accept all of the video and audio formats currently available on YouTube (H.264 or VP9 or AV1 video, AAC or Opus audio). Exception is if you are using a really old `ffmpeg`.
- `youtube-dl` is just re-muxing the video and audio with `--merge-output-format`. Like a copy and paste. There is no re-encoding so there is no [generation loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss).
- If you choose an incompatible output format, then it will fail with `ERROR: Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (copy)` or similar.

Use whichever you prefer or works best for your player/device.